Unexpected horizontal line in discrete inverse Fourier transform of Gaussian function with odd number of samples
I'm implementing a discrete inverse Fourier transform in Python to approximate the inverse Fourier transform of a Gaussian function.
While the output looks promising, I'm encountering an unexpected horizontal line when the number of samples n is an odd number.
For n = 1000 (even), the output looks correct:

For n = 1001 (odd), an unexpected horizontal line appears:

Why does this horizontal line appear when n is odd?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
My Implementation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, exp, pi, lambdify, sqrt

# Defining the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function, sqrt(pi) * exp(-omega ** 2 / 4)
x, omega = symbols('x omega')
f_gaussian_symbolic = exp(-omega ** 2 / 4) * sqrt(pi)
f_gaussian_function = lambdify(omega, f_gaussian_symbolic, 'numpy')

def fourier_inverse(f, n):
    """
    This function computes the inverse Fourier transform of a function f.
    :param f: The function to be transformed
    :param n: Number of samples
    """
    omega_max = 20 # The max frequency we want to be sampled
    omega_range = np.linspace(-omega_max, omega_max, n)

    f_values = f(omega_range)
    inverse_f = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(f_values)))

    delta_omega = omega_range[1] - omega_range[0]
    x_range = 2 * np.pi * np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=delta_omega))

    inverse_f *= delta_omega * n / (2 * np.pi)
    return x_range, inverse_f

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
x_range, inverse_f = fourier_inverse(f_gaussian_function, n=1001)
plt.plot(x_range, inverse_f.real)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.xlim(-4, 4)
plt.show()


if you convert all your np.fft.ifftshift to np.fft.fftshift it disappears and the output is centred on 0 for odd and even n

@Nin17 You are absolutely correct! It fixes it, thanks. But I'm a little confused, am I not suppose to do ifftshift after fftshift?

That "horizontal line" is not really a horizontal line. Just, the first point of your x_range, inverse_f pair is at the end. So your x axis is not sorted. And plot doesn't plot necessarily y=f(x) curves.

If you just reorder the data (so, add the first elements of the arrays at the end), for example, x=np.empty_like(x_range); y=np.empty_like(x); x[:1000]=x_range[1:]; y[:1000]=inverse_f.real[1:]; x[1000]=x_range[0]; y[1000]=inverse_f.real[0], then plot is correct. It is more a plotting problem than a fft problem.

Addition: in your case, in reality, the problem is more serious. So both my comment and the one of @Nin17 are not correct, even tho they appear to, because the gaussian is symmetric and 0 at both end anyway.

Because what you do here, is that you have a wrong shift in x, but not in y. Which answer your question to @Nin17: yes, you are supposed to reverse fftshift with ifftshift. That one is correct. But it is your fftfreq that you should shift with fftshift, not ifftshift.

So, the result in your code is that you plot a line made of points (4, f(-4)), (-4, f(-3.992)), (-3.992, f(-3.984)), (-3.984, f(-3.976)), ..., (3.984, f(3.992)), (3.992, f(4)).

Which appears to be almost correct (there is a horizontal shift of 0.008 in the gaussian, but nobody would notice that with a naked eye), but for a almost horizontal 0 line between the 2 first points (almost horizontal at 0, because f(-4) and f(-3.992) are almost equal and equal to 0)

Both @Nin17 and my comments make you just throw the first point at the end. Which remove the horizontal line. But not the 0.008 unoticable horizontal shift. Which would not be a big deal. But for the fact that it let you with your correct surprised interrogation « why should you not use ifftshift do undo a fftshift ». You should. It is only for x that you have a shifting problem.

@chrslg Thank you so much for your comments. I appreciate your time and input.

Actually, you need to swap all fftshift for ifftshift and vice-versa. fftshift is to shift the output of the fft or ifft functions. ifftshift is to shift their inputs.

This is a good explanation of the shift functions, the FFT coordinate system, etc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76376555/7328782

This question is similar to: constant lines occur in plot of fft with scipy.fftpack. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
